# facebook php api handling requests

Tags: php, facebook

I've been looking around this for a while, but haven't found any clear information. I am using the [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to send requests (obviously). In the documentation it states you should handle the requests yourself. So, my question is - what do I need to handle?

My understanding is, that you're limited to X amount of requests and if you don't clear the requests from the user, that amount will soon get filled. In the docs, it states they are sent to your app if they Accept the request, meaning we can handle this somehow but if they ignore the request, they won't get sent to I'm presuming they are automatically cleared?

So, has anyone got some example source for handling requests? - I'm using the PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best answer:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

In the last section they explain how to read requests from a user and how to delete them if necessary, examples included.

Comment: Yea thanks, I've read that already. I'd like to see if anyone has any best usage examples